# windows 10 laptop will not use bluetooth internal microphone

Tags: windows-10, bluetooth, microphone

I have several Windows 10 laptops and several wireless headphones with internal microphones.  My headphones will connect to the laptops and I can hear audio with no problem.  The problem is that although the internal microphones show up as input devices in the Sound Settings, none of my applications that record audio (Zoom, Teams, Adobe Rush) will pick up any sound from any of the headphones' internal microphones. I get the error "Your selected audio device doesn't have any input."

When I open the Windows 10 Sound Setting and go to "Device Properties and Test Microphone" and test it, I usually get a very low number like 6 or 12 percent.

Am I doing something wrong? How do I get Windows 10 applications to recognize my input device?

Comment: Bluetooth audio devices with mic only work with HFP ("Hands Free" profile) enabled - Mono LowFi audio + microphone - but the default profile is A2DP - HiFi stereo, no microphone - for music, video, etc. You must select HFP before using it with messengers requiring microphone.